# Using nuget with already referenced dependencies

Tags: nuget

I have a project with dependencies on NHibernate, Fluent NHibernate and Structuremap. Now, I want to start using Nuget to handle these dependencies and to enable updates of these dependencies.

Do I first have to manually remove these dependencies and reinstall them using Nuget, or can I just 'overwrite' these dependencies with Nuget? Are there any well known issues I can run into?

Comment: NuGet will update assemblies references (if they have the same name as ones in the package), but to be safe, remove old assembly references and install the equivalent nuget packages.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just import them via NuGet - when I did this, it replaced the references to my /Lib/ folder with the NuGet /packages/ ones.

You'll probably still want to remove the (no longer referenced) binaries from the previous location though.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2012, **Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...** is the location of where you would do this.  After installing a package, it'll ask you which projects you want to include that reference.  If the dll is already referenced, it'll simply change the path location.  You can also go back later and "manage" on Installed packages to add the DLL to new projects.